# ST3: sublimelinter-user settings ignored

Tags: python, settings, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I change the "mark_style" using the menu command and it is still in underline more. I have installed pep8 linting, anaconda, gitgutter etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have anaconda installed (but I had) and it works as expected!

Anaconda also provides pep8/linting features, you should consider disable the linting features of anaconda if you have SublimeLinter installed.

This can be achieved by setting...

```
/*
    Set is a false to disable Anaconda Linting totally
*/

"anaconda_linting": false,
```

More Infos about configure anaconda: http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings

The actual configuration file:
https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/blob/a85b3c505484dfb116470757dadd1e4a9742b276/Anaconda.sublime-settings

Comment: it turns out I have not installed pep8 and used anaconda's linting using outlines

Comment: @Nikos But you have now anacondas linting feature disabled?

Comment: it was anacond's linting from the start which used outline mark. Sublimelinter did not work because I have not pip install pep08. This is why my user settings for sublimelinter were not respected. I disabled the anaconda and installed pip08 and everything works. Basically your answer is half correct because the context of my problem was not completely described.